# Some characters not displayed when not using code markup? Confusion and panic everywhere

Tags: support, stack-overflow, markdown

I see this happen for the second time now. At first it happened when I edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086109/regex-not-working-with-similar-looking-string) to improve formatting. If you look at the comments you'll see some questions to me I didn't really know how to answer: somehow I significantly changed the code (apparently).

Now it happens again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105541/linux-command-line-regex). To understand that no harm was introduced by the edits one needs to look at the **source** of the initial revision. Has it always been that some slashes are not displayed on SO in regular text? (and in the first case, it's not only slashes: somehow `2` disappeared as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.

In most cases, Markdown uses the backslash as an **escape character**. This is why

```
<code>\\</code>
```

gives the following output:

> `\`

Escaping can be useful in a number of situations. For example, `` ​\`​ `` prints a single backtick character: `

However, the Markdown formatting for code (tab or four spaces) takes **everything** literally. In your case

```
    \\
```

gives the following output:

```
\\
```

Comment: Also note that using backticks fixes things too. It's just that [when using `<code>` one needs to HTML encode stuff manually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Lacking to do so, might make the browser interpret the tags, or might make the security parser thingy even take out unsupported tags.

Comment: I didn't even know I could use `<code>` (for the better, as I gather). However, in the questions I link to the slashes disappear in plain text, no `<code>` tags. Is this by design, too?

Comment: @LevLevitsky: Yes. As I said, it's an escape character. You couldn't write a single backtick, asterisk or underscore without it.

Comment: Yes, @Lev, as `</\\2>` probably became `</\2>` and the `<\2>` tag [is not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) (if it existed).

Comment: Ok then, thanks guys. I didn't notice before how tricky the markdown was. Another reason to use it properly (not only for nice looks). And the feeling that you've just accidentally vandalized a question is quite awkward. Should I retag my question somehow?